# Problem with import java.nio.file

Tags: java

Why this line doesn't work?

```
import static java.nio.file.AccessMode.*;
```

Eclipse says:

```
The import java.nio.file cannot be resolved
```

Here is the whole program so far:

```
import static java.nio.file.AccessMode.*;

public class CheckFileAccessibility {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

 }
}
```

I am following the official Java tutorial here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/check.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the [superordinate chapter](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html). It says:

> This section is being updated to reflect features and conventions of the upcoming release, JDK7. You can download the current JDK7 Snapshot from java.net. We've published this preliminary version so you can get the most current information now, and so you can tell us about errors, omissions, or improvements we can make to this tutorial.

So it's about java 7.